# System.NullReferenceException object reference not set to an instance

Tags: c++

I'm a beginner with C++. In my code, I am trying to get a list of the updates installed on the machine.

In my machine 1, I'm using Windows 7, and the code work perfectly.  But in machine 2, using Windows 7 too, I get the error.

I don't understand enough to know what actually needs fixing, or how to fix it.

My program stops working with the below code, and displays this error:

> unhandled exception system.NullReferenceException object reference not set to an instance

```
try
{
    HRESULT hr;
    hr = CoInitialize(NULL);

    IUpdateSession* iUpdate;
    IUpdateSearcher* searcher;
    ISearchResult* results;
    BSTR criteria = SysAllocString(L"IsInstalled=0 or IsHidden=1 or IsPresent=1");

    hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_UpdateSession, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_IUpdateSession, (LPVOID*)&iUpdate);
    hr = iUpdate->CreateUpdateSearcher(&searcher);

    //wcout << L"Searching for updates ..." << endl;
    hr = searcher->Search(criteria, &results);
    SysFreeString(criteria);

    switch (hr)
    {
    case S_OK:
        //wcout << L"List of applicable items on the machine:" << endl;
        break;
    case WU_E_LEGACYSERVER:
        wcout << L"No server selection enabled" << endl;

    case WU_E_INVALID_CRITERIA:
        wcout << L"Invalid search criteria" << endl;

    }

    IUpdateCollection *updateList;
    IUpdate *updateItem;
    LONG updateSize = 0;
    LONG totalKB = 0;
    results->get_Updates(&updateList);
    updateList->get_Count(&updateSize);

    if (updateSize == 0)
    {
        //wcout << L"No updates found" << endl;
    }

    for (LONG i = 0; i < updateSize; i++)
    {
        IStringCollection *KBCollection;
        BSTR updateName;
        LONG KBCount;
        updateList->get_Item(i, &updateItem);
        updateItem->get_Title(&updateName);
        USES_CONVERSION;
        //outputFile << W2A(CString(updateName)) << " --- ";
        updateItem->get_KBArticleIDs(&KBCollection);
        KBCollection->get_Count(&KBCount);

        for (int i = 0; i<KBCount; i++)
        {
            BSTR KBValue;
            totalKB += 1;
            KBCollection->get_Item(i, &KBValue);
            USES_CONVERSION;

            //std::string strk = streamkb.str();

            file << "{" << endl;
            std::stringstream ss;
            ss << W2A(CString("KB")) << W2A(CString(KBValue));
            std::string s = ss.str();
            list2.push_back(s);

            file << "\"Correctif" << totalKB << "\": \"" << W2A(CString("KB")) << W2A(CString(KBValue)) << "\"" << endl;
            file << "}," << endl;

        }

    }

    ::CoUninitialize();
}
catch (const std::exception & ex)
{

}
```

Comment: Does the error message tell you which line has the error?

Comment: No i get just this error and at main() at _mainCRTStartup()

Comment: Suggestion to initialize all pointers with nullptr and check every COM HRESULT. Running under debugger should give the location. Also the code leaks heavily but that wasn't your original question.

Comment: Also the code is compiled as “Managed C++” which seems unnecessary here, I see only native C++ code. The error would look different, though; it would be “Access Violation” instead (not necessarily wrapped in a C++ exception; that depends on compilation settings)

Comment: Aside form the lack of adequate error handling, you are not `Release()`ing any of the acquired COM interfaces before `CoUninitialize()` is called, and your loop is leaking COM interfaces.

Comment: `system.NullReferenceException` is not part of C++. Could this be C#?

Comment: @RemyLebeau how to make it work i'm a beginner in c++ what i should added

Comment: it's working in some devices and in another devices the app stop working and get this error unhandled exception system.nullreferenceexception object reference not set to an instance of an object at updatedfunc() at main() at _mainCRTStartup()

Comment: @PeteBecker more likely C++/CLI (ie Managed C++), which shares the same .NET framework with C#

Comment: @GoForexGoForex I already told you what to do.  You need to `Release()` a COM interface when you are done using it, and *before* calling `CoUninitialize()`. `iUpdate->Release()`, `searcher->Release()`, `results->Release()`, etc for *EVERY* COM interface you acquire, *especially* inside your loops. Just like you are calling `SysFreeString(criteria)` when you are done using `criteria` (but you are missing `SysFreeString(updateName)` and `SysFreeString(KBValue)` when you are done using `updateName` and `KBValue`, respectively).